# Find a formula that describes a given list of integers

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy

I'm trying to find some Python library or method that will create a formula that describes an an arbitrary list of integers like: `[1,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,4,1,...]`

For example:

```
from some_awesome_library import magic_method

seq = [1,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,4,1,4,3,2,2,4,3]

my_func(sequence):
    equation = magic_method(seq)
    return equation

print(my_func(seq))
```

The order of the sequence matters, but it has certain rules. For example, all integers will be between 1 and 4, and there will be an equal number of each integer within the sequence.

I've looked into `numpy.polyfit` and `scipy.optimize.leastsq`. I suspect that scipy is what I need, but it'd be great to have confirmation of that approach and any suggestions for the types of mathematical functions I should look into using (I'm not much of a math's person - just studied up to college calculus). Maybe a some sort of modulo function? Maybe a sine wave?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions you have.

EDIT: Thanks for your comments below. I'm curious about Sudoku puzzles, specifically N=2 puzzles. I suspect that if you take the entire solution space and line them up in a certain order that patterns will emerge that might be useful for solving Sudoku faster. I've got a class that represents the solution space called `SolutionManager` and returns "slices" of the solution space that look like the list of integers shown above. Below is an image of one such example for an N=2 puzzle solution space (generated with Jupyter Notebook):

[image: SudokuSolutionManager]

I think I can see patterns in the data, but I'm trying to figure out how to develop formulas that represent these patterns. I also suspect that reordering the solutions will make for simpler equations describing those patterns.

To prove that I'm trying to write a genetic algorithm that will reorder the solutions described in the SolutionManager according to how simple the equations describing them are. I'm stuck on writing the fitness function, which should rate the SolutionManager instance by how simple it's described equations are.

Code for the SolutionManager is below:

```
class SolutionManager:
    """Object that contains all possible Solutions for an n=2 Sudoku array"""

    def __init__(self, solutions_file):
        input_file = open(solutions_file, 'r')
        grids = [r.strip() for r in input_file.readlines()]
        list_of_solutions = []
        i = 0
        for grid in grids:
            list_of_cubes = []
            i += 1
            for r in range(4):
                for c in range(4):
                    pos = r * 4 + c
                    digit = int(grid[pos])
                    cube = Cube(i, c, r, digit)
                    list_of_cubes.append(cube)
            list_of_solutions.append(Solution(list_of_cubes))

        self.solutions = list_of_solutions
        assert isinstance(self.solutions, list)
        assert all(isinstance(x, Solution) for x in self.solutions)

    """Get a vertical slice of the Solution Space"""

    def get_vertical_slice(self, slice_index):
        assert slice_index <= 4
        assert slice_index >= 0
        slice = []
        for sol in self.solutions:
            slice.append(sol.get_column(slice_index))
        return slice

    """Get a horizontal slice of the Solution Space"""

    def get_horizontal_slice(self, slice_index):
        assert slice_index <= 4
        assert slice_index >= 0
        slice = []
        for sol in self.solutions:
            slice.append(sol.get_row(slice_index))
        return slice

    """Sorts the solutions by a vertical axis using an algorithm"""

    def sort_solutions_by_vertical_axis(self, axis_index):
        pass


class Solution:
    def __init__(self, cubes):
        assert (len(cubes) == 16)
        self.solution_cubes = cubes

    def get_column(self, c):
        return list(_cube for _cube in self.solution_cubes if _cube.row == c)

    def get_row(self, r):
        return list(_cube for _cube in self.solution_cubes if _cube.column == r)

    def get_column_value(self, c, v):
        single_cube = list(_cube for _cube in self.solution_cubes if _cube.row == r and _cube.value == v)
        assert (len(single_cube) == 1)
        return single_cube[0]

    def get_row_value(self, r, v):
        single_cube = list(_cube for _cube in self.solution_cubes if _cube.column == c and _cube.value == v)
        assert (len(single_cube) == 1)
        return single_cube[0]

    def get_position(self, r, c):
        single_cube = list(_cube for _cube in self.solution_cubes if _cube.column == c and _cube.row == r)
        assert (len(single_cube) == 1)
        return single_cube[0]

class Cube:
    def __init__(self, d, c, r, v):
        self.depth = d
        self.column = c
        self.row = r
        self.value = v

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify - do you want a method to describe/analyse such a list?  Or do you want a method to generate such a list?

Comment: Note that even if magic_method exists, for most sequences, the complexity of the equation will be similar to the complexity of the initial sequence, that is to say the length of the equation's code will be roughly proportional to that of the sequence.

Comment: Finding a library (or type of mathematical function) for you is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: One "function" that woould work is, for a given `seq`, that `seq[k]` is the remainder when a number `n` is divided by the `k`th prime number (saying that the 0th prime number is 2). The [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) guarantees that there are infinitely many `n`s for a given sequence `seq`. Would that do?

Comment: This question is not off-topic, but it need serious refinition as to what is the expected outcome of the code.

Comment: Oops, to allow for the first entry to be up to 4, we need the 0th prime number to be 5. The primes would just continue from there.

Comment: Can you show us what you want to be able to use the resulting "equation" for?